# How do I check what version of 'cifs-utils' I have installed?

Tags: mount, cifs

I am trying to mount my Buffalo NAS:

```
/etc/fstab:

//192.168.2.20/Movies /mnt/Movies cifs rw,noexec,nosuid,password=Password1,username=buffalonas,nodev
```

When execute the following command, I am getting the error below:

```
crash@crash-M17x:/sbin$ sudo mount -a

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //192.168.2.20/Movies,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

I have read via other forums that I need to update or install `cifs-utils` because I currently do not have `/sbin/mount.cifs` file, only mount.files I have are `mount.ntfs`

But when I execute:

```
crash@crash-M17x:/sbin$ sudo apt-get install cifs-utils

Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
cifs-utils is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So how do I know if I have the latest `cifs-utils`? and if I already do have the latest, how do I install the `mount.cifs` files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the version and where it comes from with this command:

```
apt-cache policy cifs-utils
```

With this command you can see all the files that the package installs:

```
apt-file list cifs-utils

cifs-utils: /etc/request-key.d/cifs.idmap.conf
cifs-utils: /etc/request-key.d/cifs.spnego.conf
cifs-utils: /sbin/mount.cifs
cifs-utils: /usr/bin/cifscreds
cifs-utils: /usr/bin/getcifsacl
cifs-utils: /usr/bin/setcifsacl
cifs-utils: /usr/sbin/cifs.idmap
cifs-utils: /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall
cifs-utils: /usr/share/doc/cifs-utils/NEWS.Debian.gz
cifs-utils: /usr/share/doc/cifs-utils/README
cifs-utils: /usr/share/doc/cifs-utils/changelog.Debian.gz
cifs-utils: /usr/share/doc/cifs-utils/copyright
cifs-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/cifscreds.1.gz
cifs-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/getcifsacl.1.gz
cifs-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/setcifsacl.1.gz
cifs-utils: /usr/share/man/man8/cifs.idmap.8.gz
cifs-utils: /usr/share/man/man8/cifs.upcall.8.gz
cifs-utils: /usr/share/man/man8/mount.cifs.8.gz
```

As you can see it installs `/sbin/mount.cifs`.

And finally with this command you can check if all the md5sums are correct:

```
dlocate -md5check cifs-utils
```

Comment: Why am I character limited in my comments?

So I did that and here is the end result:

crash@crash-M17x:/sbin$ dlocate -md5check cifs-utils
md5sum: sbin/mount.cifs: No such file or directory
sbin/mount.cifs: FAILED open or read

I can't display all the results because of character limitations.

Comment: Ok, so this file is missing. Try reinstalling the package: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall cifs-utils`

Comment: Re-installing cifs-utils fixed the problem.